# Как экранировать слеш в JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста.
Есть вот такой код

```
mypath=homeDir.replace(/Applications/test/Contents/Resources/profile/g,"local_images");
alert (mypath);
```

В нем хочу заменить `Applications/AvtoBot_v0.0.1.app/Contents/Resources/profile` на `local_images`  но вот не знаю как эти / слешы екранировать.

Comment: так кавычки или слешы? у вас заголовок и тело отличается.

Comment: экранировать слэш: `\/`

Comment: @lexxl Извените уже исправил название.

Comment: @Sublihim  спасибо за подсказку. Все верно.

Comment: Прими какой-нибудь правильный ответ нажатием на галочку.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Есть 4 способа экранирования - 3 из них такие же как для строк:

- обратный слеш: `\/` - обычно используется именно он
- шестнадцатеричный код: `\x2F`
- юникодный шестнадцатеричный код: `\u002F`

и четвёртый уникален для регулярок:

- квадратные скобки: `[/]`

```js
var s = "qwea/bra/brr";

console.log(s.match(/a\/b/g).join(" "));
console.log(s.match(/a[/]b/g).join(" "));
console.log(s.match(/a\x2Fb/g).join(" "));
console.log(s.match(/a\u002Fb/g).join(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Экранировать слэш (как и многие другие символы) можно через обратный слеш: `\/`
Также можно использовать спецсимволы: `\u002F`

Comment: Есть ещё способ :)

Comment: @Qwertiy хитро)

Answer (score 1):

Про экранирование уже всё написали, поэтому дополню другим способом инстанциировать регулярку:

```
new RegExp('Applications/test/Contents/Resources/profile', 'g')
```

Это может стать особенно полезным в `String.prototype.replace`, потому что строка для замены может быть получена из стороннего источника, а единственный вариант множественной замены предполагает `RegExp` с флагом `global` в первом параметре:

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[|\\{()[^$+*?.-]/g, "\\$&");
}

mypath = homeDir.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(getBasePath()), 'g'), 'local_images');
```

В этом сценарии необходимо заэкранировать все спецсимволы, что и делает функция `escapeRegExp`.

Comment: Проблема. Если в строке есть обратные слеши, скобки, точки и ещё куча всего, то их надо экранировать. Нельзя просто так брать строку и отвдавать в конструктор регулярки.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо! Исправил)

Comment: Ага. Только в квадратных скобках экранировани почти не требуется - ты несколько перестарался :) А replace all ещё можно сделать через split-join.

Comment: Я ж не сам его писал) Обновил из [репозитория](https://github.com/sindresorhus/escape-string-regexp) на githube

Comment: А вот квадратные скобки экранировать стоит. И куда делись закрывающаяся квадратная и фигурная? А ещё github - не youtube :)

Comment: закрывающие экранировать не обязательно же. `на github'e`

Comment: А это стандарт или всё-таки из допустимых расширений синтаксиса? Хотя, там вроде другое: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-RegExp_syntax_extensions

Answer (score -4):

```
var mypath=homeDir.replace("/Applications/test/Contents/Resources/profile/g","local_images");
```

Comment: Нет, это не php.

Comment: Там литеральная регулярка, а не строка.